# Add Keyboard short cut to WinForm App

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a kbrd short cut like this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>. This sequence is common in visual studio. I would like to add it to my application.

To use it, press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then press <kbd>D</kbd>. Next, release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>. Finally, press <kbd>1</kbd>. This should execute the desired function.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The OP Needs VS Style Shortcuts. For exmple for example the sequence  Ctrl+D , Ctrl+1 to perform the action. I wonder why such question down voted! The OP just has no Idea about how to do such job.

Answer (score 1):

It is a chord, not just a single keystroke.  So you must *first* detect the Ctrl+D keystroke, then the 1.  Use a variable to remember that you saw Ctrl+D, like this:

```
private bool ctrld;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
    if (!ctrld && keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.D)) {
        ctrld = true;
        return true;
    }
    if (ctrld) {
        switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode) {
            case Keys.D1: DoStuff(); break;
            // others...
        }
        return true;
    }
    ctrld = false;
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Note that as written (keyData & Keys.KeyCode) it will recognize 1 regardless of the modifier key state.  So Ctrl+1 will work as well.  Usually desirable, remove the & if you want to recognize only 1.  Some sort of feedback that you are in the "Ctrl+D state" on a status strip would be wise, compare to what VS does.